# Navigating to the method of the references DLL

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am running some unit test which calls a method in a separate assembly (DLL). When I call that method it blows up and gives an error. Is there anyway I can step into that method (In a different DLL) from my unit test while debugging?

I am using VS 2010 and MSTEST

Comment: You should be able to if you have the source or pdb file for that dll

Comment: even when the `Dll` doesn't have source code somewhere? debugging this way can be done at low-level with `C++` :)

Comment: Only a DLL reference has been added to the project.

Comment: @johndoe what if you can debug into that `Dll`? Try fixing it and recompile another version? Well it's not easy I think.

Answer (score 2):

You should't need to test an `external method`, since this is out of your control anyway.  You're better off mocking/stubbing the call to the Method, and testing the flow.

There's an [article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) on the subject.